# 301 redirect & htaccess RewriteEngine conflicting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

My site uses RewriteEngine to hide variables in the URI as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?/([^/\.]+)/?$ page.php?theme=$1&pg=$2 [L]
```

This works fine, but as we're relaunching, we've got a few 301 redirects to handle as well. I've added these below my rewrite rules, here's an example:

```
redirect 301 /about/about-the-site https://www.mywebsite.com/about-us
```

The problem is, that it's redirecting but adding extra crap to the url string:

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/?theme=about&pg=about-the-site
```

Any idea why this would be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mix `mod_alias` and `mod_rewrite` rules as these 2 modules execute at different stages. Keep everything in `mod_rewrite` itself:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^about/about-the-site/?$ https://www.mywebsite.com/about-us? [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?/([^/.]+)/?$ page.php?theme=$1&pg=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Also note extra `?` in the target URL to strip any pre-existing query string. Make sure clear browser cache while testing it.

Comment: Thank you!! I didn't realize there was a difference between mod_alias & mod_rewrite. As a sidenote, I added `$` at the end of the url so that it wasn't greedy: `RewriteRule ^about/about-the-site$ https://www.mywebsite.com/about-us? [L,NC,R=301]`